# getting a parameter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get the "weatherdata" parameter from GetDatas() function in my h4. I have been trying for a while now, but I don't know how to do it.

```
function GetDatas(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(cityname)
         fetch(cityURI)
        .then(city => city.json())
        .then(citydata => {
        fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${citydata[0].lat}&lon=${citydata[0].lon}&appid=${key}`)
            .then(weatherdata => weatherdata.json())
            .then(weatherdata => {
                return weatherdata
            })
        });
    }

       return (
        <div className="cityinput">
            <form onSubmit={() => {GetDatas();}}>
                <label >City name</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => SetCityname(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <div>
                <h4>Name: {weatherdata.name}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Instead of `return weatherdata`, set state, and then read that state in the render?

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your component which also defines the state as this could be relevant to prevent infinite loops from happening. I imagine `citydata` and `cityname` are states?

Comment: They are, I just had to create a state for the weatherdata as well and that solved my problem. Idk why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Store your weatherData response in a state variable. And use that state variable to conditionally render your weatherData.name in your  JSX. i.e., `{weatherData && weatherData.name && <h4>{weatherData.name}</h4>}`